# How can I improve font rendering in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome, fonts, antialiasing

I have Gnome Teaks installed and have enabled full hinting and sub-pixel anti-aliasing but fonts still look horrible. How can I fine-tune font anti-aliasing in 18.04?

Comment: Can You share a screenshot showing the font issue ?